# Weird Improper Integral - A possible complex constant?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am wishing to test the convergence of the following integral and find the value of (where convergent):

$$\int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{1}{x(\log(1/x))^c} dx$$

For all $ c \in \mathbb{R} $.

My first step is factoring out the $\frac{1}{(-1)^c}$ of the integral.

Like so:$$\frac{1}{(-1)^c} \int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{1}{x(\log(x))^c} dx$$

However, for some non-integers of c, this will give me a complex number. So when I find the limit of a variable tending to 0 (for the integral limit), like this

$$\lim_{t \to 0^+}\frac{1}{(-1)^c} \int_{t}^{1/2} \frac{1}{x(log(x))^c} dx$$

Won't I have that, because it's complex, there exists no such limit? Or can I factor this out of the limit, so the existence of the limit is irrespective of this constant - Can you do this with improper integrals?

Thank you.

Comment: You could just make a substitution for $log(x)$ and then integrate with that negative sign with the log

Comment: You are on the wrong track. $\log(1/x) = -\log x > 0$ on the interval.  For $c \leqslant 0$ you have $\frac{1}{x (-\log x)^c } > \frac{(\log 2)^{-c}}{x}$ which implies divergence by comparison.  Now consider $c > 0$. Otherwise just compute the integral.

Comment: I agree totally with @RRL. By introducing the $(-1)$, you have made things much more difficult for yourself. After all, in your range, $\log x$ isn’t positive either, and raising it to nonintegral $c$ gives the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\dfrac{1}{x\left(\ln\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^c}~dx$

$=\int_\infty^{\ln2}\dfrac{1}{e^{-x}\left(\ln\dfrac{1}{e^{-x}}\right)^c}~d(e^{-x})$

$=\int_{\ln2}^\infty\dfrac{1}{x^c}~dx$

The integral converges when $c<-1$ .